# Pyelliptic with Pickle fails sometimes

Tags: python, python-3.x, openssl

If i run the following testcase several times with:

```
python3 -m unittest test_pyelliptic.py
```

roughly one out of 15 runs fails.

TestCase:

```
import unittest, pyelliptic, pickle

class PyellipticTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.alice = pyelliptic.ECC()
        self.bob = pyelliptic.ECC()

    def test_pickleSign(self):
        tm = {"text":"contract","amount":12}
        tms1 = {"doc":tm,"c1":self.bob.get_pubkey(),"s1":self.bob.sign(pickle.dumps(tm))}
        tms2bb = {"doc":tms1,"c2":self.alice.get_pubkey(),"s2":self.alice.sign(pickle.dumps(tms1))}
        tms2 = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(tms2bb))
        self.assertEqual(tms2['s2'],tms2bb['s2'])
        self.assertTrue(pyelliptic.ECC(pubkey=self.alice.get_pubkey()).verify(tms2bb['s2'],pickle.dumps(tms2['doc']))) #<--- FAILs sometimes
```

My System:

- OS: 14.04.1-Ubuntu (Kernel 3.16.0-36-generic)
- Phtyon3: Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:18)
- OpenSSL: 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
- pyelliptic: 1.5.7

I also tested this on a similar system with Python 3.4.3 and could reproduce the behavior.

Can you reproduce the fault on your System?
If yes, what causes it?

**Update**

If I run the test with verbose (python3 -m unittest -v test_pyelliptic2.py) it produces the following output (run twice):

```
X@X:~/test$ python3 -m unittest -v test_pyelliptic2.py 
test_pickleSign (test_pyelliptic2.PyellipticTestCase) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.012s

OK
X@X:~/test$ python3 -m unittest -v test_pyelliptic2.py 
test_pickleSign (test_pyelliptic2.PyellipticTestCase) ... FAIL

======================================================================
FAIL: test_pickleSign (test_pyelliptic2.PyellipticTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "XX/test/test_pyelliptic2.py", line 14, in test_pickleSign
    self.assertTrue(pyelliptic.ECC(pubkey=self.alice.get_pubkey()).verify(tms2bb['s2'],pickle.dumps(tms2['doc']))) #<--- FAILs sometimes
AssertionError: False is not true

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.013s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

After some further research it turns out that the binary pickle output depends on the ordering of the elements in the dictionary.
Therefore the following test case fails at the comparison of the binary arrays:

```
def test_pickleOrder(self):
        d1 = {"test1":12,"test2":14.2,"test3":"test"}
        d2 = {"test3":"test","test1":12,"test2":14.2}       
        self.assertEqual(d1,d2)     
        d1p = pickle.dumps(d1)
        d2p = pickle.dumps(d2)      
        self.assertEqual(d1p,d2p) #<--- fails here
```

BTW: this is not only the case for pickle, but also for json and bson modules